# HTML5 Colspan - alternative

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am using 'colspan' in one of the td tags in my HTML. I don't want to use 'colspan' in my HTML. But still i need to achieve the function that is been achieved by 'colspan'. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Any reason not to use the default way to achieve the result?

Comment: Dont use tables. Use floated divs in a grid instead.

Comment: @Sirko, Because the html will be send to back end for some processing, which does not accept colspan. So to avoid that we need to find an alternative.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a hack to cope with another hack. You're sending *HTML* to the backend for processing, and it doesn't "accept" colspan? Very odd, might want to provide some context here, or process your data in another way.

Comment: Filtering out the Colspan can help... we can use jQuery `removeAttr()` function to remove the colspan and submit the div.

Comment: @jtheman: tables are fine for displaying data like spreadsheets and whatever, as long as it's not used to define site structure.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve colspan via css style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `colspan` can be simulated using a table with dummy empty cells `<td></td>` for the slots that are to be spanned and absolutely positioning the cell that should span them. You need a relatively positioned wrapper `div` for the table, since you cannot directly make the table the frame of reference for positioning.

It gets rather ugly, especially since you need to worry about the row height – because making a cell absolutely positioned takes it away from table formatting. You could deal with this by using a copy of the cell content as the content of the dummy cell to be spanned. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp6wz/).

It get complicated, so any software that cannot handle a simple `colspan` may fail to deal with this too (at least if it is responsible for *rendering* the document).

Comment: empty cells don't emulate a colspan... they just add a bunch of columns. colspan spans multiple columns into one column

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input#submitHtml', function(){
    $('htmlToSend').find('tr').removeAttr('colspan');
    // Submit the form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid like structure, using divs.

```
<div>
    <div class='headerrow'>

    </div>
    <div class='bodyrow'>
        <div class='bodycell'>

        </div>
        <div class='bodycell'>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```