# Alternative to colspan in HTML or css

Tags: html

I would like to know if it is possible to use any alternative for the colspan in HTML. I have a table with colspan. That table goes to backend for processing to convert as pdf. However, when I am trying to convert as a pdf it could not handle the colspan as an expected. I am wondering if there is any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically I have a existing HTML table. It uses colspan which is working fine in HTML view meaning in the browser. However, I need to generate the PDF the html page that I have. I am sending the HTML content to the backend for processing but It does not understand the colspan. So, I am looking for any alternative that actually does the job for colspan. Can I used flow layout using html table? One more problem is I can't change the layout (using div) which requires redesign the whole thing which is not possible.

Comment: What are you using to convert to pdf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Colspan - alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621126/html5-colspan-alternative)