# Border around a column in a html table with certain rows having a collspan

Tags: html, html-table

I have an HTML table displaying a calendar.
People are divided in groups. The names of the groups can be very long.

Two requirements :

1. Don't let the name of the group (in the screenshot 'The name of a group can be very long') have any influence on the width of the columns with the names.
2. A border should be drawn around the complete column that is "today".

For requirement 1, I simply set a `colspan` on the `td` containing the name of the group.

```
<td colspan="31">The name of a group can be very long</td>
```

For requirement 2, I set a border on the correct `column` in the `columngroup`.

```
<colgroup>
   <col>
   <col>
   <col>
   <col class="planningtable_todaycolumn">
</colgroup>
```

Now the issue is that the border breaks on the group rows, instead of just continuing.

How can I fix this?
I have been looking into fixing problem 1 in another way than using a `colspan`. Because when I'm not using a `colspan` the issue is solved automatically. But I could not find usable solutions.

Also been thinking about another way to draw the border. But in the group row, there is no element to give a border, so I have no idea how to fix that.

[image: Example]

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621126/html5-colspan-alternative

Comment: Thanks man, I found a solution by reading that post.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the link @Bobtroopo provided I came up with a solution :

Don't use a colspan for the group cells.

But give them a position style :

```
position: absolute
```